# How to make write a chrome extension which is always enabled for any urls?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, to do some modification to the page content, but I have to click on it to make it working on current page.

What I want is: if I click on the extension icon (to enable it), it will always enabled, no matter what new pages/tabs are open, and will work on them?

How to write code to configure it?

Comment: Use chrome.declarativeContent to register/unregister the content script or run it manually with chrome.tabs.executeScript inside chrome.tabs.onUpdated (or chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted) listener.

Answer (score 1):

Using [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) you can achieve this. Content scripts are files that run in the context of web pages so you can modify webpage content.

Add below code in manifest.json

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["your-content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "tabs", "http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

To learn more, read this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#arch